# Google Search Console deadlock: Unable to remove URL so I can index a different URL

Tags: google-search-console

I recently tried some SEO tweaks to see if I could improve traffic to my personal website. One of these changes was shortening some of my URLs. This worked just fine for about 4-5 of the URLs that I changed, except for one.

The problematic URL is

`https://aleksandrhovhannisyan.github.io/blog/dev/how-to-add-a-copy-to-clipboard-button-to-your-jekyll-blog/`

Which I shortened to

`https://aleksandrhovhannisyan.github.io/blog/dev/jekyll-copy-to-clipboard-button/`

The former URL no longer exists on my website, and I did not set up a 301 redirect. Instead, I requested that Google remove it from search results via Google Search Console. I also requested that it index the new URL.

Basically, I'm in a bizarre deadlock situation where Google refuses to index my new URL, claiming it selected the old one as a canonical because of "duplicate content":

[image]

According to the Removals page, the old URL was in fact removed:

[image]

But when I inspect this old URL, Google Search Console claims the URL is on Google:

[image]

**How do I get out of this mess?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks for the feedback! I wonder why the `google-search-console` tag exists, then.